# Fetching and Sorting inside React Function

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-redux

So I have a sort function and button inside a component and while the sorting logic is correct, nothing is being re-rendered when I click the button since there is no fetch for the menus. The button is supposed to sort all of the menu cards in alphabetical order. How should I write this syntax wise? Do I need to map through all of my menu cards as well?

Previously I had the sorting being done using a reducer case and an action but now want to do it without using actions or reducers.

Component:

```
class MenuFilter extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super(); 
      this.state = { menus: [] };
    }

    handleMenuFetch = e => {
        this.props.fetchMenus()
    };

    handleMenuSort = e => {
      this.setState({
          menus: [...this.state.menus].sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a.name < b.name) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a.name > b.name) {
              return 1;
            }

            return 0;
          })
      })};


    render() {
      return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
              <div>
                  <button id="show-button" onClick={this.handleMenuFetch}>Show Menus</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <button id="sort-button" title="Sort Menus" onClick={this.handleMenuSort}>Sort Menus</button>
              </div>
            </Row>
        </Container>
        )
      }

    }
```

Comment: javascript sort() doesn't return sorted content https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: how are you setting an initial values for menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
handleMenuSort = e => {
      let menus= [...this.state.menus].sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a.name < b.name) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a.name > b.name) {
              return 1;
            }

            return 0;
          });
      this.setState({
          menus
      })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using setState, use this.state to store the result of 
the sorting and then use setState to re-render the updated values.

```
handleMenuSort = e => {
      this.state.menus= [...this.state.menus].sort(function(a, b) {
            if (a.name < b.name) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (a.name > b.name) {
              return 1;
            }

            return 0;
          });
      this.setState({
            menus
})
};
```

Comment: I am getting the 'teams' is not defined error for the line under 'this.setState'

Comment: can you share the screenshot?

Comment: https://imgur.com/jBVKRrc its the same error except menus instead of teams

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize your menus by mapping them in your jsx block:

```
<Row>
  <div>
    {this.state.menus.map(el) => el.name}
  </div>
</Row>
```

And make sure that your `handleMenuFetch` is populating your initial menus by setting state and that each item being set has a 'name' property:

```
handleMenuFetch = e => {
  this.setState({
    menus: [{name: item1}, {name: item2}, {name: item3}, etc...]
  })
};
```

Comment: Could you show how it looks like inside when you add this to handleMenuFetch and render()? I tried adding it but am getting errors for undefined menu#(replaced item#). Also is (el) argument element in the map?